# Where can I enter my contribution for Maryland College Investment Plan in TurboTax Online?

Tags: united-states, income-tax, 529-plan, turbotax, maryland

I'm a Maryland resident who contributed $2500 to each of my two daughters' Maryland College Savings Plans.

That should entitle me to a $5000 Maryland state tax deduction.

Now I'm trying to do my taxes using Turbo Tax Online (self-employed product)

I tried following the instructions [here](https://ttlc.intuit.com/community/state-taxes/discussion/maryland-allows-deductions-for-529-accounts-where-is-this-addressed-in-the-online-product-for/00/776749) but those instructions seem incorrect.

- Log into your return and click Take me to my return **(I did this!)**
- Click on State and then Your State Returns at top of screen **(I did this!)**
- If you have already entered your state, click Edit/Continue **(I did this!)**
- Go through state portion until you see the screen that says Here’s the income that Maryland handles differently **(It doesn't say "Here's the income that Maryland handles differently" anywhere!)**

How should I enter the information about these two contributions and get my $5000 deduction??

Answer (score 1):

I have not done this for the Maryland form, but I used to do it for Virginia.

> Go through state portion until you see the screen that says Here’s the
> income that Maryland handles differently (It doesn't say "Here's the
> income that Maryland handles differently" anywhere!)

I know for the Virginia you have to go through multiple screens before you get to this section. Turbo Tax asks if you moved, they ask you about the county you live in, and they ask about investing in specific businesses.

Eventually you get to that "Here’s the income that Maryland handles differently" screen.

I assume that while each list is state specific, Turbo tax makes the path to that screen similar for each state.